# Amazon EC2 instance Problems with UDP transmission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, udp, inetaddress, unknown-host

I have been trying to send an UDP packet from an EC2 instance to itself. I received an exception:

**java.net.UnknownHostException: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Name or service not known**

It was generated from the line:

**DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, InetAddress.getByName(destination), RPCServer.PORTNUM);**

I am sure this exception is from InetAddress.getByName(destination), in which destination is a string of the raw IP address of my EC2 instance. Could anyone tell me how I can get around this exception?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using Inetaddress.getByAddress(DESTINATION), here DESTINATION is a byte array converted from the IP string destination.